# How to format upto two decimal digit in R?

Tags: r

I have the R output like:

```
y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.128976, 0.38794344, 2.39485800, 0.2345667)
```

How can I format it up to two decimal digits?

Comment: You can check `?round`

Comment: `round(y,2)` as was stated before. Plus have a look at options(scipen = 2) . Besides there's `format`

Comment: There's also `sprintf("%.2f", y)` or `formatC(y,format="f",digits=2)` if it is merely a matter of displaying the data.